# Spring Data and Oracle returns different result from query? Why?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My JPA query is very complex because of that I am using nativequery, But when I run it returns different results from JAVA query and Oracle query. However Oracle query returns correct result.What could be the reason for this ?

I changed SELECT statement, try to fetch all of them by a.* and also try to fetch only necessary column. I also remove DATE comparison statements. However interestingly JPA query returns 4 row and all of them were same exactly. I also try to fetch data without TRUNC keyword in DATE comparison part, and it is not worked. In addition I add schema names in front of tables in native query which is not worked again.

```
public Optional<LocalDateTime> getPaymentPeriod2(LocalDate reportDate, String loanId)
{



final String reportDateParemeter = reportDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    final String query = "SELECT st.t_no, st.islem_tarihi, st.s_kodu, st.odeme_suresi " +
                "FROM k_tarihce st, k_tanim sta, kt_tanim tta " +
                "WHERE st.s_kodu = sta.s_kodu " +
                "AND tta.s_tipi = sta.s_tipi AND tta.t_kodu = st.t_kodu " +
                "AND st.t_no = :loanId AND st.t_kodu in (37,55) " +
                "AND st.s_kodu = 'K1' AND (TRUNC(st.odeme_suresi) >= TRUNC(TO_DATE(:reportDateParemeter,'yyyy-mm-dd')))";

    final Query loanGetPaymentPeriodQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query, LoanStatusHistory.class);
        loanGetPaymentPeriodQuery.setParameter("reportDateParemeter", reportDateParemeter);
        loanGetPaymentPeriodQuery.setParameter("loanId", loanId);
        List<LoanStatusHistory> loanStatusHistoryList = loanGetPaymentPeriodQuery.getResultList();

        return loanStatusHistoryList.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(loanStatusHistoryList.get(0).getPaymentPeriod());
    }
```

And my entity is:

```js
@Entity
@Table(name = "K_TARIHCE", schema = "LOS")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Cacheable(false)
@IdClass(LoanStatusHistoryId.class)
public class LoanStatusHistory {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "T_NO")
    private String loanId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ISLEM_TARIHI")
    private LocalDate processDate;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "S_KODU")
    private String statusCode;
    @Column(name = "ODEME_SURESI")
    private LocalDateTime paymentPeriod;
    @Column(name = "T_KODU")
    private String historyCode;
}

class LoanStatusHistoryId implements Serializable {
    private String loanId;
    private transient LocalDate processDate;
    private String statusCode;
}
```

I want to same result with Oracle SQL developer. My main objective is fetch ODEME_SURESI field.

Comment: Welcome aboard Doruk, show us the results you get with Oracle along with the query used with Oracle. Also show us the result you get with the ORM strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, again !interestingly! Here my new code below, I just not mapped my native query with entity, and return some LocalDate.

```js
final Query loanGetPaymentPeriodQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
            loanGetPaymentPeriodQuery.setParameter("reportDateParemeter", reportDateParemeter);
            loanGetPaymentPeriodQuery.setParameter("loanId", loanId);
            final List<LocalDate> loanStatusHistoryList = loanGetPaymentPeriodQuery.getResultList();

            return loanStatusHistoryList.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(loanStatusHistoryList.get(0));
```

This is the only change I made. I still not know why it worked?.